# Get rest of the string after cutting last two string

Tags: php

i have a variable value which may contain

```
     309  
    1208
   31802
```

Now, i need to get 3/12/318. mean the rest part of the string after cutting last two string.how can i do it in php.

Comment: `substr($value, 0, -2)` as shown in __example #2__ in the [PHP docs for substr()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.substr.php)

Comment: Why don't you use substr() function ?

Answer (score 2):

Do it like that:

```
substr($string, $start, $length)

substr($string, -3, (strlen($string)-2) * -1);
```

With this expression, you start at the third from last char of the string and select all the remaining chars to the beginning.

PHP-Documentation for substr: http://php.net/manual/de/function.substr.php

Answer (score 2):

Another way is dividing by `100`

```
<?php
echo (int)(309/100)."\n";
echo (int)(1208/100)."\n";
echo (int)(31802/100)."\n";
?>
```

https://eval.in/628062